# Python CSV file reader : bad cells format for high numbers

Tags: python, csv, format

I'm using the csv file reader of python to read a csv file. My code is the following :

```
with open(self.csv_file, 'rb') as csvfile:
        data = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';'))
```

Everything works fine except for one column of my csv file. I have columns with float numbers that are between 1 and -1 (ex : 0,34430203959) and it works perfectly but one of my column is dealing with very high numbers (ex : 142266963436).Because the cells of the file are formatted as "standards", my CSV file is printig the number 142266963436 as 142.266.963.436 (as shown in the figure below) :

[image]

There is the problem. When I parse my CSV file, he has no problems dealing with little numbers because there is only one "." but when I parse high numbers with a lot of "." python interpret them as "float" and put the "." after the fist number.

So, instead of having the number :

```
142266963436
```

I have the number :

```
1.42266963436
```

Anyone has an idea of how i could fix this ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm guessing you're in a Euro-type area where `.` is a thousands separator in numbers?

Comment: No, Python would never do that; there is some other confusion here. Python reads the data as *strings* only. Can you show us the `repr()` of an offending column please?

Comment: And don't confuse what Excel will display with what is actually stored in the CSV file on disk.

Comment: open you csv file with a plain text editor and look at that cell again.

Comment: Well @MartijnPieters, when I open the csv file with Notepad i got the same problems (the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx). And when i print data.__repr__() i got this : "'-0.13197804738', '-0.394402020945', '124.871.043.056', ..." so same problem here. Any ideas?

Comment: and yes I'm from Europe @MarcB

Comment: So your file *itself* contains that data. By the looks of it all your `z` coordinates are formatted like that. Are those supposed to be floating point values?

Comment: If these are interpreted as floats between -1 and 1, they all can be 'repaired' by removing the dots and pre-pending `0.` before interpreting as floats. Are there any that are negative (start with a -)?

Answer (score 2):

Your CSV file contains that oddity; it looks as if all your `z` columns are afflicted (`ankle_pos.z` and `toe_pos.z` in your screenshot). If you are certain these values are meant to be floats then you can use Python to 'repair' these:

```
import csv

def repaired_float(c):
    try:
        return float(c)
    except ValueError:
        # interpret ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd as 0.ddddddddd instead
        return float('.{}'.format(c.replace('.', ''))

with open(filename, 'rb') as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh)
    next(reader, None)  # skip header row
    for row in reader:
        row = map(repaired_float, row)
        # do something with row
```

If you wanted to interpret those values as (large) integers, replace the last 2  lines in `repaired_float()` with:

```
# interpret ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd as ddddddddd instead
return int(c.replace('.', ''))
```